# Receive GCM Data in Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, event-handling

I'm receiving data from server by GCM. I want to update ListView on Activity. But, when I receive the data, it is in BroadcastReceiver. How do I send that data to Activity so that I can update the ListView.

Edit:

I'm developing an RSS app. First, I am using MainActivity to get all the RSS data from my own server and display it in ListView. I use GCM to get notification when the new data is added to the server. I get the new data in separate class and store this data in `List<FeedItem>`. But, the problem is I don't know how to send the new `List<FeedItem>` data to MainActivity to display it. It is like "New Feeds" in FaceBook.

Comment: where is your mainActivity and another activity?

Comment: Too less information. Show your code at least.

Comment: What you have tried yet???

Comment: I'm sry for the less info ,  But I'm working on Rss app , first I use mainActivity to get all the Rss from my own Server and display them in listview , and use GCM Tech. to get notification when the new data add to the server , and I get the new data in separate class and store this data in List<FeedItem>, all these work well , but the problem is I don't know how to send the new List<FeedItem> to mainActivity to display them ,,,
<it's like New Feed in FaceBook>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive data in receiver you need to broadcast that again.and set broadcast receiver in activity when you get that broadcast Update the list.

```
public void sendBroadcast() 
{
   Intent intent = new Intent("send");
   intent.putExtra("current speed", "102.4");
   intent.putExtra("latitude", "12.2342342");
   intent.putExtra("longitude", "12.21124");
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `broadcast reciver` or `interface` to update your list view.
and onother solution,for your case, is to use service.
as i use following code in my service:

```
   public void updateConversationUi() {
    if (mOnConversationUpdate != null) {
        mOnConversationUpdate.onConversationUpdate();
    }
}
```

where `onConversationUpdate` is interface which called while any change came for list view.